# Set UITableViewCell label to be generated from HTML string

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uitableview

I'm using TableView on swift and I would like to know how can I set the UITableViewCell label to be generated from HTML string.

I know how to use it to present text on the cell label:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    var articlesInSection = xmlParser.channelsArray[indexPath.section]["articles"] as [AnyObject]

    //articleWebView.loadHTMLString(activeItem, baseURL: nil)

    cell.textLabel?.text = articlesInSection[indexPath.row]["title"] as NSString

    return cell
}
```

but I have an HTML I want to present instead of the text, something similar to loadHTMLString function

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use NSAttributedString to show text from html but I don't think this is very efficient solution inside table view cell because it can cause lag while scrolling and/or delay while loading

```
var attrStr = NSAttributedString(
            data:yourHTMLString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
            options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
            documentAttributes: nil,
            error: nil)
cell.textLabel?.attributedText = attrStr
```

Comment: Thanks! it works, I need it only for test app since I don't have the original app code so the lagging is fine for me

Comment: Can I do the same for the section header?

Comment: Yes you could do that for any label

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AttributedString`
Sample in `Swift 5`

```
do {
   let attrStr = try NSAttributedString(data: htmlStr.data(using: .unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: [.documentType : NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
   cell.textLabel?.attributedText = attrStr
} catch {
   print(error)
}
```